# How to programmatically retrieve information like language, OS, Architecture, etc. regarding the current project

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm pretty new to IntelliJ plugin development and I was wondering if there's the possibility to retrieve some information regarding the current project (or better the current edited file).
The information I'd like to have access are the following:

- Language (e.g. Java, Groovy, etc.)
- Architecture (e.g. x86, x64, etc.) and OS (WindowsXP, LinuxUbuntu, MAC OS X, etc.) of the machine where IntelliJ is running onto
- For Java projects, JVM used to build the project

I'm extending a DumbAwareAction and in the actionPerformed(AnActionEvent event) method I found something like this:

```
Project project = event.getData(PlatformDataKeys.PROJECT);
```

...but I cannot find such information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick look into Community Edition source code helped to compose the following:

```
Sdk projectSdk = ProjectRootManager.getInstance(project).getSdk();
```

For module:

```
Sdk moduleSdk = ((ModuleRootManagerImpl)ModuleRootManager.getInstance(module)).getSdk();
```

Cannot tell anything about Architecture or Language.

Comment: I'm fine with the first solution, thank you so much! Regarding the Language, I added some guess on file extension...